# Computing Double Integrals Using Green's Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Consider the region $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1/2 \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 2\}$, i.e, an Annulus with inner radius $1/2$, outer radius $2$. I would like to compute:
$$
\iint_A 2x - 2ye^{x^2+y^2} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
$$
I would like to compute this using Green's theorem, i.e., rewriting the above integral as a line-integral. The default statement of Green's theorem motivates us to set:
$$
\partial_xQ = 2x
$$
$$
\partial_yP = -2ye^{x^2 + y^2}
$$
Thus, we have that:
$$
Q = x^2 + C(y)
$$
$$
P = e^{x^2 + y^2} + C(x)
$$
after integrating the derivatives with respect to $x,y$, respectively. Given, this, how should I go about computing:
$$
\oint_{\partial A} P \mathrm{d}x + Q \mathrm{d}y
$$
?

Comment: I think you can drop the C's. What exactly are you having trouble with? Finding the curve corresponding to $\partial A$?

Comment: Yes, I am having issues parameterizing the curve and integrand. Would I have to switch to polar coordinates?

Comment: Yes, polar coordinates looks like the way to go.  $\partial A$ consists of two circles with opposite orientations.